# How to make COUNT AS in Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

So I have this query:

```
select u.*, count(mi.media_id) as media_count
from user as u
left join media_items as mi on mi.user_id = u.user_id
where u.is_enabled = 1 and
group by u.user_type
having media_count > 0;
```

I'm trying to translate it to a Zend_Db_Select. So far I have everything but the count of the media. This is what I tried:

```
$select->from(array('u' => 'user'), array('*', new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(mi.media_id) AS media_count'))
       ->joinLeft('mi' => 'media_items'), 'mi.user_id = u.user_id')
       ->where('u.is_enabled = 1')
       ->group('u.user_type')
       ->having('media_count > 0');
```

This gets me the error:

```
"Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'media_count' in 'having clause'"
```

How do I create this statement the Zend way?

Also, I outputted the query that this created and ran it on MySQLWorkBench and it ran just fine.

Edit
I've just tried:

```
->columns('media_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(mi.media_id)'))
```

Same error.

Comment: When you say you outputted the query and ran it to test, do you mean you did `echo $select`? And this produced the right SQL?

Comment: $select->__toString() is how I got the raw query generated.

Comment: Weird then, not sure why this doesn't work. `>having('COUNT(mi.media_id) > 0');` should work as a workaround

Comment: Yup, I tried that finally and that works. Was hoping to figure out why the other way doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work properly :

```
$select->from(array('u' => 'user'), array('*', 'media_count' => 'count(mi.media_id)'))
   ->joinLeft('mi' => 'media_items'), 'mi.user_id = u.user_id')
   ->where('u.is_enabled = 1')
   ->group('u.user_type')
   ->having('media_count > 0');
```